# Getting fatal error during transformation while running JMETER script through ANT

Tags: ant, jmeter

I have a Jmeter script which downloads pdf from an application. The script works perfectly fine when I run the script through JMETER GUI (Screenshot 1). Also, I am able to see the generated pdf in Response section (Screenshot 1).

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLa2V.png)

But when I try to run the same script through ANT(Build.xml), the script is getting failed with the below error (Screenshot 2).

BUILD FAILED
E:\Apache\apache-jmeter-3.2\extras\build.xml:128: Fatal error during transformat
ion using E:\Apache\apache-jmeter-3.2\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl
: Character reference "&#x14" is an invalid XML character.; SystemID: file:/E:/A
pache/apache-jmeter-3.2/extras/Overview.jtl; Line#: 332772; Column#:
25

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Dj6.png)

Is there something extra I need to add in Build.xml to generate pdf through ANT? The script is failing when jtl file is transforming into html file. The script is unable to generate html report because of invalid characters in jtl file. 
Can someone help me with this.

I have created a sample script which downloads pdf. Please find the script in the below link.
[JMX script which downloads pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07964835052136851870)

The above script is working fine when I run through JMETER GUI 
(screenshot 3) 
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yTms.png).I am able to see generated pdf in response section.
But when I run the same script through Ant, I am getting below error(screenshot 4).
[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKKMp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I have attached the script.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably .jtl results file is corrupt due to unescaped [&#x14](http://www.codetable.net/hex/14) character. If you are storing response data in .jtl file - please don't as it causes massive disk IO and might have negative impact on your test.

Try running your script like:

```
ant -Dshow-data=n ...
```

Or locate the following line in *build.xml* file:

```
<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
```

and amend it to be

```
<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="false"/>
```

References:

- [JMeter Properties Reference: Results File Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thank you so much for the information. I have changed my build.xml as proposed and ran my script but still i am getting the same exception.

Comment: Show line 332772 of your .jtl file, please

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I have created a sample script which downloads pdf. please find the jmx script in the below link. http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07964835052136851870

Comment: for the sample pdf generation script, when i run through Ant, i am getting fatal error exception. Please find the jtl file in the below link. http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=38477902978268426590

Comment: Don't save response data, it is not required for HTML report generation with Ant. The relevant setting is `<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data" value="false"/>`. You will need to re-run your test to re-generate .jtl file. If you need response data for any other reason - just add a [Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats) and configure it to save response data into a **separate** file